# Page redirect and load file into div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have index.php in which I would like when the user clicks the button "Click" it to redirect to "newpage.php" but also for another page "Click.php" to be loaded into the div "content" within the newly loaded "newpage.php".
Similarly I would like for when "Click Also" is clicked for the user to be redirected to the same page "newpage.php" but a different page "ClickAlso.php" to be loaded into the same div "content".

**index.php**

```
<html>  
    <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(document).on('click', '.clickme', function() {
            window.location.replace("newpage.php");
          });

          $(document).on('click', '.clickmealso', function() {
            window.location.replace("newpage.php");
          });
        });
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div>
        <button class="clickme">Click</button>
        <button class="clickmealso">Click Also</button>
      </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

**newpage.php**

```
<html>    
    <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {});
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="content">
      </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Use url params to differentiate between versions and php includes based on those url params. Would be simpler to use href in `<a>` tags as per normal site navigation

Comment: @charlietfl apologies but can you elaborate on your suggestion?

Comment: use links not buttons and javascript to navigate. Use url parameters ( easily searched on web) to differentiate content to display

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks but my difficulty is when the new page loads there does not seem to be a way to update the content div as the only operation performed when clicking on the buttons is to load the page. I don't see how this could be fixed by using links or adding in url parameters

Comment: the url parameter would dictate which content...and you can use server side include or ajax to set the content

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

**index.php**

change your *document ready* event to redirect to newpage.php using url params. For this example I used a parameter named 'page'.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.clickme', function() {
      window.location = ("newpage.php?page=click");
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.clickmealso', function() {
      window.location = ("newpage.php?page=clickAlso");
    });
});
```

**newpage.php**

Define what happens once the page is accessed. This is where things get a bit more interesting. Each time this page (newpage.php) loads, it looks for the parameter 'page' in the URL and extracts its value. The parameter's value is then assigned to a variable I called `$pageToGet`.
After that we check whether the value is equal to `'click'` or `'clickAlso'` and we display the content accordingly using `require`.

```
<?php 
  $pageToGet = $_GET['page'];
?>
<html>    
    <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="content">
        <?php 
            if ($pageToGet == 'click') {
                require('Click.php');
            } elseif($pageToGet == 'clickAlso') {
                require('ClickAlso.php');
            }
        ?>
      </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Be sure to have your files: **Click.php** and **ClickAlso.php** in the same directory for this to work.

Good Luck